# Selectively rendering Liquid templates?

Tags: ruby, liquid

Is there a possibility to selectively render specific tags in a liquid template and leave the rest for a second render?

I have pages containing snippets(includes) and variables. The snippets are stored in the database and expensive to render. The variables are available only at runtime (via the URL request in the scenario of a landing page). I want to cache the page content with the snippets rendered but with all the rest of the liquid markup untouched.

So, If I have

```
{% snippet header %}

{% if vars.first_name %}
Welcome, {{ vars.first_name }}
{% endif %}

{% snippet footer %}
```

I would want the cached page content to be:

```
The header content

{% if vars.first_name %}
Welcome, {{ vars.first_name }}
{% endif %}

The footer content
```

At runtime this would be picked up from the memcached store and rendered:

```
The header content

Welcome, John

The footer content
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

**Update: Here's what I have in place already:** 
(It works, but I am looking for a cleaner, ideally liquid-only-based solution.)

A "vars" tag which produces a variable with the given name:

```
{% vars first_name %} #=> {{ vars.first_name }}
```

And, I use modified liquid markup for everything I don't want rendered the first time:

```
{* if vars.first_name *}
```

So, currently the initial page looks like this:

```
{% snippet header %}

{* if vars.first_name *}
Welcome, {% vars first_name %}
{* endif *}

{% snippet footer %}
```

Which gets rendered once and cached as:

```
The header content

{* if vars.first_name *}
Welcome, {{ vars.first_name }}
{* endif *}

The footer content
```

Then at runtime I retrieve the cached version and replace `{*` with `{%` etc. to get

```
The header content

{% if vars.first_name %}
Welcome, {{ vars.first_name }}
{% endif %}

The footer content
```

Which I render with liquid again to get to the desired outcome.

This does the job but is not pure liquid and I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Is there?

Comment: I don't know Liquid, but I would think you could craft the body as a snippet that gets rendered, but produces more Liquid markup. As long as you can run it back through the rendering phase, it would then render the Liquid tags that were produced in the first pass of rendering. I would assume Liquid has some way to escape the characters it uses as tags and markup. Or you could use another tempting engine like ERB to produce the first render with the snippets written in ERB.

Comment: Bear tech, I agree. I already tried this by defining a tag called vars which renders into a variable markup at first pass. {% vars first_name %} -> {{ vars.first_name}}. It works. I am mainly looking for a workaround for the conditionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% snippet header %}

{% raw %}{% if vars.first_name %}
Welcome, {{ vars.first_name }}
{% endif %}{% endraw %}

{% snippet footer %}
```

This should get you the rendering that you want to cache, and then if you re-render it through Liquid I would think it would process the runtime variable.

Comment: This looks like it should work... Thank you. Not sure if I'll go with it as it may be a little too complicated for the end users. I guess there's no perfect world; I may end up just instructing them to use `{* *}` markup for conditionals and logic (see my update to the question). This way I have consistent tags for vars and snippets and for "everything else."

Comment: Would it be cleaner if you made the second pass content a snippet also? That way the end users would just put their content in a snippet called "body" and your template would have `{% raw %}{% snippet body %}{% end raw %}` This would be pure Liquid since it's just the regular liquid markup in the snippets and it just gets passed through the rendering engine twice?

Comment: I think the complexity comes from my choice to cache at the page level which leads to the need for two-pass rendering. If I cache at the snippet level (bypass db calls for individual snippets), I can let liquid do its thing. So I think I'll do a benchmark and likely move the caching layer to simplify things. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please let us know in these comments how snippet caching compares to page caching in your results. Curious to know the final outcome.